# What is this inlet part on a lawnmower muffler?

Tags: part-identification, emissions, lawnmower, muffler

I have noticed a small box on the bottom of the muffler on a Mountfield SV150 lawnmower engine.

[image: Exhaust with inlet box]

Inside is a reed valve set up as inlet only and a small filter grill.

What is the purpose of this part? I understand these are catalytic mufflers, could it be to prevent some pressure differential? Thank you

Comment: I allows fresh air (oxygen) into the cat during hard deceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually to add air to the hot exhaust gas to make sure that the catalyst can cause the reaxtions to breakdown the combusted products sufficiently.